# Chart show custom labels on x-Axe with automatic labels

Tags: c#, charts

I have a problem with my chart.
I'm creating chart with numeric values (X-axe for time and Y-axe for velocity)
I have 3 series graphs on one Chart.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/vy6lw1b0lj2ql96/graph1.jpg

As you can see on X-Axe i don't see any labels with values, besides my only created customer label.
What i wanted to do is to add my customer labels with relevant X values for each series graph to existing auto values with predefined intervals, so when i added the following line:
timeChart.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.CustomLabels.Add(1, 1.5, "test");
all the rest of the auto-generated labels just disappeared.

When i remove the mentioned line then i can see the default values for my chart:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/5u2v8b60pgup4wd/graph2.JPG

I read a lot of forums but didn't find proper solution for me.
On every forum - the solution was to configure the following line which didn't work for me:
timeChart.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.Interval = 1;
I tried to change a lot of stuff in Chart propertied but it still is not working as expected.

I'm attaching the code:

```
            timeChart.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.Interval = 1;
            timeChart.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.Minimum = 0;
            timeChart.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.Maximum = m_totalTime + 1;

         //   timeChart.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.Interval = 1;
            timeChart.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.Minimum = 0;
            timeChart.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.Maximum = m_maxVelocity + 1;

            timeChart.Titles["mainTitle"].Visible = true;
            timeChart.Legends["Legend1"].Enabled = true;
            distanceChart.Legends["Legend1"].Enabled = true;
            distanceChart.Titles["mainTitle"].Visible = true;

            //timeChart.Series["Time Chart A"].IsXValueIndexed = true;
            //timeChart.Series["Time Chart B"].IsXValueIndexed = true;
            //timeChart.Series["Time Chart C"].IsXValueIndexed = true;


            timeChart.Series["Time Chart A"].Points.AddXY(0, 0);
            timeChart.Series["Time Chart A"].Points.AddXY(m_nodeAT1Time, m_maxVelocity);
            timeChart.Series["Time Chart A"].Points.AddXY(m_nodeAT1Time + m_nodeAT2Time, m_maxVelocity);
            timeChart.Series["Time Chart A"].Points.AddXY(m_totalTime, 0);

           timeChart.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.CustomLabels.Add(1, 1.5, "test");

          //  timeChart.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.Interval = 1;
            timeChart.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.Interval = 1;
            timeChart.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.LabelStyle.Interval = 1;
            //timeChart.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.LabelStyle.Enabled = true;

            timeChart.Series["Time Chart B"].Points.AddXY(0, 0);
            timeChart.Series["Time Chart B"].Points.AddXY(m_nodeBT1Time, m_nodeBVelocity);
            timeChart.Series["Time Chart B"].Points.AddXY(m_nodeBT1Time + m_nodeBT2Time, m_nodeBVelocity);
            timeChart.Series["Time Chart B"].Points.AddXY(m_totalTime, 0);

            timeChart.Series["Time Chart C"].Points.AddXY(0, 0);
            timeChart.Series["Time Chart C"].Points.AddXY(m_nodeCT1Time, m_nodeCVelocity);
            timeChart.Series["Time Chart C"].Points.AddXY(m_nodeCT1Time + m_nodeCT2Time, m_nodeCVelocity);
            timeChart.Series["Time Chart C"].Points.AddXY(m_totalTime, 0);

            timeChart.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.IsMarginVisible = true;
            timeChart.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.Interval = 1;
```

I will appreciate your assistance.

Thank you.

Comment: That is how CustomLabels work by design: Either them or the normal ones. They never are displayed together.

Answer (score 0):

You misunderstood the difference between an axis label and title. Your code is very messy so I'll move by steps: first bind the data.

```
timeChart.Series["Time Chart A"].Points.AddXY(0, 0);
//...
timeChart.Series["Time Chart C"].Points.AddXY(m_totalTime, 0);
```

then set the titles of your axes

```
timeChart.AxisY.Title = "Times(s)";
timeChart.AxisX.Title = "Speed (m/s)";
```

This should work. However, You might want to force the chart to have a certain interval on the axes

```
timeChart.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.Interval = 1;
timeChart.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.Interval = 1;
```

or a minimum or whatever. The chart should this way get your data, create the axis labels with them and display them in the correct way.

It could also be useful to tell the chart what kind of data you are inputting

```
foreach(Series s in timeChart.Series)
{
    s.XAxisType = AxisType.Double; //autocomplete should help you there, I can't remember the correct object
}
```